# How do i get word2vec similarity from the mean vector?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, word2vec

For example, there are words for 'apple', 'banana', and 'orange'.

We will execute the code below to save the distance between apple and banana.

```
model.similarity('apple', 'banana')
```

But what I want to know is the similarity between 'apple' and 'whole fruits'.
How do i get the similarity of apples and whole fruits?

I already got vectors for the whole fruit.
e.g. `whole fruits=[0, 0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 0.5, .....]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

model.similarity calculates cosine similarity behind the scenes between the embedding vectors for the words. If you have already have the vectors for "apple" and "whole fruits" then you can get the cosine similarity using [sklearn's pairwise cosine similarity function.](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity.html)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're probably using the `gensim` library's word-vectors support, so your `model` is some variant of its `KeyedVectors` type.

If such a set-of-word-vectors `model` already has a vector for the string token `'whole fruits'`, then you can use the exact same call as with `'apple'` and `'banana'`:

```
model.similarity('apple', 'whole fruits')
```

If instead your vector for `'whole fruits'` is not already in the model, but coming from somewhere else, you'll have to calculate the cosine-similarity yourself. You could use the [scikit-learn utility function in Adnan S's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62918202/130288), or use the same sort of calculation as is happening inside `gensim`'s `.similarity()` method:

```
import numpy as np
from gensim import matutils

vec1 = model.word_vec('apple', use_norm=True)
vec2 = matutils.unitvec(your_whole_fruits_vector)
cos_sim = ns.dot(vec1, vec2)
```